# Generalization of xy plane in 3D space

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider an $m$ dimensional subspace of an $n$ dimensional space that is obtained by zeroing $n-m$ dimensions of the super-space. Does such a subspace have a specific name?

Answer (score 1):

Well if $m=n-1$ such a subspace is called a hyperplane. I don't know of any other specific naming for a subspace with dimension less than $n-1$...